# y contains previously unseen labels: 'Male' in Label encoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I am trying to convert the categorical column of my dataset into numerical using LabelEncoder.
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIyTf.png)

Here is the conversion code:

```
for i in cat_columns:
    df[i]=encoder.fit_transform(df[i])
```

After conversion dataset looks like [dataset after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J05E2.png)

But the problem is whenever I try to transform my test dataset it gives an error that

```
y contains previously unseen labels: 'Male'
```

Code for transformation on test data :

```
for i in cat_columns:
    df1[i]=encoder.transform(df1[i])
```

[test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdDQK.png)

Now how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using the same encoder to fit all the different columns. You should instead fit each column using a different encoder. For example, you can use a dictionary to store the different encoders:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

encoders = {}
for i in cat_columns:
    encoders[i] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    df[i] = encoders[i].fit_transform(df[i])
    
for i in cat_columns:
    df1[i] = encoders[i].transform(df1[i])
```

---

The error you encounter (`previously unseen labels: 'Male'`) is caused by the fact you are trying to transform the `gender` column using the last encoder you create in the previous for loop, which in your case might be a `smoking_status` label encoder.